# Cant find on Jisho and dont know top kanji?

Tags: meaning

I looked on Jisho as others recommended and so far I see Akete can be happy new year but i dont know the first kanji at the top or how id look it up. I see it says utsukushi for beautiful. So my guess is the sentence is happy new year....[image: happy]

Edit: Someone mentioned I can maybe draw the kanji on Jisho so I will try that also. I dodnt know that.

Edit edit: okay so far what i got is, "Yoru(night) ga happy new year, asahi(morning sun) beautiful." Which doesnt really make sense.

Comment: Check the meaning of うつくしい again.

Comment: It says 夜. Try this site: https://kanji.sljfaq.org/draw.html

Comment: I see. I was mixing up Ureshi with Utsukushi. So beautiful asahi then? Beautiful morning sun...

Comment: Thanks for that site. Looks good! Ill start using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you arrived at 'happy new year', but you're overcomplicating it.
あけて should be the te-form of 明ける and in this case it has meaning 6) or 7) on [this page](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%98%8E%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B).

The translation is a bit confusing because 夜が明ける literally means 'the night ends' hence the translation of 'dawn'. The rest of your translation is fine.

Comment: Question for someone else: When writing this answer I noticed that Jisho  has an entry for 夜が明ける and it spells 夜 as よ rather than よる. Is this the normal way to say it? Is よるがあける weird?

Comment: Thank you for this! I see I must of looked at the wrong thing. So essentially it says, "The night ends, beautiful morning"? Does it imply that the night just ended and a beautiful morning is here?

Comment: @FruitBasket Don't forget that i-adjectives have 'to be' built into them so 朝日がうつくしい means the morning sun **is** beautiful.

Comment: よるがあける is fine.